# Link providers with Auth UI in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

From the recent I/O conference it was mentioned in one of the talks that account works in auth ui, this [wasn't the case previously](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/139) but is now also mentioned as a possibility in the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseAuthUI/README.md)

> The FirebaseUI Auth component implement best practices for authentication on mobile devices and websites, which can maximize sign-in and sign-up conversion for your app. It also handles edge cases like account recovery and account linking that can be security sensitive and error-prone to handle correctly.

The feature however remains undocumented (from what I can figure out) for the time being (which is understandable since they have *just* launched it :)). But I was wondering wether anyone is clued in if this in fact is implemented and if so, how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

They mean account linking when for example you sign up with Email A using provider 1 (google) and then try to sign in with a new provider 2(Facebook) which shares the same Email A, FirebaseUI will automatically link both accounts. Typically in that case, you would get an error that the credential exists. You would need to first sign back in with Email A using Google and then link the new Facebook credential to it. By doing so, the user is able to sign in with either providers in the future.

Comment: So what you are saying is, if I sign in a user anonymously the instant they open the app, then if they go to sign in with an already existing account the Firebase Auth UI will automatically sign the anonymous user out and login with the existing user. And if no user exists it will link the accounts?

Comment: Anonymous user upgrade is not supported. If a user is signed in anonymously, they will be logged out in the process of signing into FirebaseUI. Please file a request for it on their GitHub repo. That is the best place to do so.